# How to show item selected from dropdown should not appear in checkbox list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

[image]

On my page there is a dropdown list of items (Main Complaint) and a checkbox list on a popup (Additional Complaint) as shown in above image.

The popup checkbox list of Additional Complaint is like below (There are more items in my list so list is in four columns):

[image]

**HTML code**

```
 <label class="question-name" ng-class="{error:hasError()}">  <span class="ng-binding" ng-hide="question.nameHiddenOnMobile">Main Complaint </span>  <span class="icon-required" ng-show="question.required"></span>  </label>

<select name="Language.PrimarySpoken" ng-hide="showAddAnswer" ng-model="question.response.value" ng-options="a.text as a.getText() for a in question.answers.items" id="Language.PrimarySpoken" ng-value="a.text" class="input-wide " ng-class="{error:hasError()}" ng-change="selectAnswer()">
   <option class="hidden" disabled="disabled" value=""></option>
        <option value="One">One</option>
        <option value="Two">Two</option>
        <option value="Three">Three</option>
        <option value="Four">Four</option>
        <option value="Five">Five</option> 
        <option value="Six">Six</option> 
        <option value="Seven">Seven</option> 
        <option value="Eight">Eight</option> 
</select>


 <label class="question-name" ng-class="{error:hasError()}">  <span class="ng-binding" ng-hide="question.nameHiddenOnMobile">Additional Complaint </span>  <span class="icon-required" ng-show="question.required"></span>  </label>

         <div class="form-row added ng-binding content" ng-bind-html="question.getText()" id="text" ></div>
       <div class="form-row addlink ng-binding" ng-bind-html="question.getText()"><em><a class='inline' href="#inline_content">+ Add/Edit</a></em></div>

  <div style='display:none'>
   <div id='inline_content' style='padding:25px; background:#fff; font-size: 17px;'>
<form action="" id="popup_form">
    <div class="added">

        <div class="column-left">
                <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox1" style="font-size:20px;">
                <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="One" id="checkbox1" data-toggle="checkbox">
                One
                </label>
                <br/>
                <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox2" style="font-size:20px;">
                <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Two" id="checkbox2" data-toggle="checkbox">
                Two
                </label>
                <br/>
        </div>

        <div class="column-center">
                <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox3" style="font-size:20px;">
                <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Three" id="checkbox3" data-toggle="checkbox">
                Three
                </label>
                <br/>
                <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox4" style="font-size:20px;">
                <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Four" id="checkbox4" data-toggle="checkbox">
                Four
                </label>
                <br/>
        </div>

        <div class="column-center-right">
            <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox5" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Five" id="checkbox5" data-toggle="checkbox">
            Five
            </label> 
            <br/>
            <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox6" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Six" id="checkbox6" data-toggle="checkbox">
            Six
            </label> 
            <br/>
        </div>

        <div class="column-right">
            <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox7" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value=" Seven" id="checkbox7" data-toggle="checkbox">
            Seven
            </label> 
            <br/>
            <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox8" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Eight" id="checkbox8" data-toggle="checkbox">
            Eight
            </label> 
            <br/>
        </div>

    </div> 
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="update" class="button button-orange" style="width: 90px; margin-top: 450px;
margin-left: -533px;" value="Update">
<input type="submit" name="cancel" id="cancel" class="button button-orange" style="width: 90px; background-color:#36606e;" value="Cancel">
</form> 

</div>
</div>
```

**JS code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true,opacity:0.7, fixed:true, innerWidth:1100, innerHeight:550, scrolling:false});

  //array to store checkbox values
            checkValues = new Array();

            document.getElementById('update').onclick = function(){
                        //capture all text in a variable
                        var textStr = $('<ul></ul>');
                        //iterate all checkbox values to create ul
                        $.each(checkValues, function( index, value ){
                              textStr.append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
                        });
                        //add text
                        $("#text").html(textStr);
                        parent.$.colorbox.close();
                        return false;
            };

             //add change handler for checkbox        
           $('input:checkbox[name=complaint]').change(function(){
               value = $(this).val();
               if(this.checked)
                   checkValues.push(value);
               else
               {   //Removing by value
                  checkValues = $.grep(checkValues, function(n, i) { 
                      return n !== value;
                  }); 
               }
          });    

          document.getElementById('cancel').onclick = function(){
               parent.$.colorbox.close();
                        return false;
          };

            });
```

Question:

If the 'One' item is selected from the dropdown list of *Main Complaint*, then in the *Additional Complaint* checkbox list that 'One' item should **not** appear like below. But the empty space also should not be there.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me, how do I get that working using Jquery/JS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u share the fiddle of that code piece?

Comment: you have put the question nicely but where is your JS code ??

Comment: Which function opens the popup can you share?

Comment: @Siddharth I was not able to create fiddle. So shared code that I have.

Comment: @Yo Yo I have JS code for popup(used colorbox) and displaying values of popup items on page. Added that much of JS code above.

Comment: @ progrAmmar I have used colobox for popup. When I click on '+ Add/Edit' link popup opens. I have added JS code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not develop a modal window in fiddle but i have written Javascript logic, hope you will find it helpful, working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydyqrdo4/)

JAVASCRIPT

```
function selectAnswer(sel){   
    var a= document.querySelectorAll('label');
    console.log(this.value);
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
     a[i].style.display='inline'


   }
    document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox'+sel.value)[0].style.display='none';
}
```

while i change your `onchange` function to this->

```
onchange="selectAnswer(this)"
```

Hoping this helps you.

Comment: I applied your code but that is not working somehow in my code. And also the empty space in checkbox list should also disappear. Do we have to use name of checkbox(complaint) in JS code?

Comment: listen, do one thing call my function just after you have loaded the model window

Comment: we are doing it by `class`, name would be used later/on backend.

Comment: oh..i see..you have changed the class of checkbox in HTML also. This is working now. But there becomes empty space if we select inbetween item. Can you update your answer such that next item will take removed item's position in checkbox list?

Comment: What if I have space or other characters in the value of dropdown item? e.g. `<option value="One number / two number">One number / two number</option>` then I have to do like this `<label class="checkboxOne number / two number" for="checkbox1" style="font-size:20px;">` What is solution for this?

Comment: you gotta make some relation between, selected option and label, you can introduce custom attribute to `option` and get that done.

Comment: With your second solution also I am getting empty space in my case :(

Comment: i think it is because your html is not structured properly, you are implementing table layout using divs, try implementing row layout of bootstrap,

Comment: Its not working. I think `inline-block` is not getting applied through `for loop`

Comment: can u make a fiddle?

Comment: as mentioned in above comments also, I tried to create fiddle but I couldn't able to make it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. There is one small problem. In your fiddle can you please check, why the first item is not removing at very first time when we load the page? The same problem is coming with my case also. e.g. 'One' at first time we remove when page load then its not removing. but after we delete any item and remove 'One' then its deleted.

Comment: it is because your first field is disable and it is rendering like this it is not triggering 'onchange', if you want to trigger manually that is totally fine or try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3abncyLn/)

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div style="display:none">
            <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox1" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Three" id="checkbox3" data-toggle="checkbox">
            One
            </label>
        </div>
        <div >
            <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox1" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Four" id="checkbox4" data-toggle="checkbox">
            Two
            </label>
            <br/>
        </div>
```

add div to all labels and apply the css property "display:none" when you click the checkbox hope this will work

Comment: The checkbox should disappear after we select dropdown item, not when we click on checkbox. e.g. if 'One' selected from dropdown then 'One' from popup checkbox list should disappear.

Comment: when you select dropdown than apply that display:none to that checkbox div it will work i think..